# Django: Filter for specific object

Tags: python, django

The `type` of `questions_and_answers` is `<class 'modeltrans.manager.MultilingualQuerySet'>`. I wrote the following code and wonder if there is a better/shorter way. I was looking into this here: `filtered_dict = {k: v for k, v in questions_and_answers.items() if v.focus == QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN}` but I always get back **'MultilingualQuerySet' object has no attribute 'items'**

```
 questions_and_answers = self.request.event.surveys.get_results(settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT)
            for question in questions_and_answers:
                if question.focus == QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN:
                    context["feeling_about_attending_again"] = question
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I now found a solution:

```
context["feeling_about_attending_again"] = list(filter(
    lambda question: question.focus == QuestionFocus.FEELING_ABOUT_ATTENDING_AGAIN,
    questions_and_answers
))
```